# How can I group monthly over years in Python with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset ranging from 2009 to 2019. The Dates include Years, months and days. I have two columns: one with dates and the other with values. I need to group my Dataframe monthly summing up the Values in the other column. At the moment what I am doing is setting the date column as index and using "df.resample('M').sum()". 
The problem is that this is grouping my Dataframe monthly but for each different year (so I have 128 values in the "date" column). How can I group my data only for the 12 months without taking into consideration years? 
Thank you very much in advance

I attached two images as example of the Dataset I have and the one I want to obtain.

[Dataframe I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOdVK.png)
[Dataframe I want to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBr04.png)

Comment: Can you please give us an example how your output should look like?

Comment: Ok I put it now.

Answer (score 0):

use dt.month on your date column.

Example is

```py
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.month).agg({'value':'sum'})
```